# Swig Typemap for Array

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, swig

Can any one suggest me How to write Typemap for Array. This is my sample cpp file

```
#include<iostream>
int array(int &result[])
{
 int n[ 10 ];


   for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
   {
      result[ i ] = i + 1; 
   }
   return 0;
}
```

How to write (array.i) dot i file for above cpp code with TypeMap